# Add a property with .map() in rxjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rxjs, rxjs5

If I had an object *car*:

```
{
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Sonic"
    type: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Tiny"
    }
}
```

And I wanted to manipulate the object to add a typeId property:

```
{
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Sonic"
    type: {
        id: 1,
        name: "Tiny"
    },
    typeId: 1
}
```

Which rxjs operator would you use, assuming you had an array of these objects? This is what I'm trying to avoid:

```
someArray.map(item => ({
    make: item.make,
    model: item.model,
    type: item.type,
    typeId: item.type.id
}));
```

Comment: If you're just adding, why not `someArray.forEach(o => o.typeId = o.type.id)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Rewriting the entire model, because the model I'm using is much larger than this car. ;-)

Comment: @adeneo Why not? Because I wasn't thinking about forEach. Nicely played, sir.

Comment: @adeneo Feel free to submit that as the answer. Meanwhile, I can't stop laughing at myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a property in each object in the array, you could use `forEach` as you don't have to map the array

```
someArray.forEach(o => o.typeId = o.type.id)
```